# Kendo, Grid, Detail, expandRow()

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a grid that uses a detail template. By default, all the detail rows are closed.

When I expand one of them and perform an edit, I would like the grid to reload with that master-row open.

In my update fuction, I do this. The important stuff is in UPPER-CASE:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: actionUrlSanc,
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        objData = JSON.parse(data); // CF gives us back a serialised struct, so deserialise it!
        if (objData.BSUCCESS == true) {
            // REMOVE THE POP-UP EDITOR WINDOW
            kendoWindow.close().destroy();
            // RELOAD THE DATASOURCE
            $('##offencesGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
            // OPEN THE MASTER-ROW OF THE JUST-EDITED DETAIL ROW
            // WHAT DO I DO HERE???...

        } else {
            alert(objData.SZERRMSG);
            return false;
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorMsgSanc + "\n" + xhr + "\n" + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

I know that in the databound node of the grid I can make ALL the master-rows expand by using this:

```
this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row"));
```

And I can make the first master-row expand by doing this:

```
this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
```

But I think I need some way of passing the master row from my update function into the expandRow() function.

Can anyone advise?

---

### UPDATE 1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("##offencesGrid").kendoGrid({
        detailInit: sanctionDetail
        [the grid code... cut out for clarity/brevity]
    });

    function sanctionDetail(e) {
        masterRow = e.masterRow;
        [the dataRow code... cut out for clarity/brevity]
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: actionUrlSanc,
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        objData = JSON.parse(data); // CF gives us back a serialised struct, so deserialise it!
        if (objData.BSUCCESS == true) {
            // REMOVE THE POP-UP EDITOR WINDOW
            kendoWindow.close().destroy();
            // RELOAD THE DATASOURCE
            $('##offencesGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();        // New data is returned from database to datasource 

            // OPEN THE MASTER-ROW OF THE JUST-EDITED DETAIL ROW
            console.log(masterRow);                         // Yep! I see the row, no problem!
            try {
                $("##offencesGrid").data("kendoGrid").expandRow(masterRow); // Nothing happens, dammit!!!
                console.log("no error");                    // This prints to console
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err);                       // We do not arrive here, therefore no error
            }

        } else {
            alert(objData.SZERRMSG);
            return false;
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorMsgSanc + "\n" + xhr + "\n" + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

---

### UPDATE 2

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: actionUrlSanc,
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        objData = JSON.parse(data); // CF gives us back a serialised struct, so deserialise it!
        if (objData.BSUCCESS == true) {
            // REMOVE THE POP-UP EDITOR WINDOW
            kendoWindow.close().destroy();
            // RELOAD THE DATASOURCE
            $('##offencesGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();        // New data is returned from database to datasource 

            // OPEN THE MASTER-ROW OF THE JUST-EDITED DETAIL ROW
            var grid = $("##offencesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            console.log(grid.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row"));            // No problem. Three children in the object 
            console.log(grid.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row"):nth-child(1));       // ERROR. "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"
            //grid.data("kendoGrid").expandRow(masterRow);  


        } else {
            alert(objData.SZERRMSG);
            return false;
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorMsgSanc + "\n" + xhr + "\n" + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

---

### UPDATE 3

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: actionUrlSanc,
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        objData = JSON.parse(data); // CF gives us back a serialised struct, so deserialise it!
        if (objData.BSUCCESS == true) {
            // REMOVE THE POP-UP EDITOR WINDOW
            kendoWindow.close().destroy();
            // RELOAD THE DATASOURCE
            $('##offencesGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();        // New data is returned from database to datasource 

            // OPEN THE MASTER-ROW OF THE JUST-EDITED DETAIL ROW
            var grid = $("##offencesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            var masterRow=1; 
            console.log(grid.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row:nth-child("+masterRow+")"));   // The row prints       
            grid.expandRow(grid.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row:nth-child("+masterRow+")"));    // The masterRow expands momentarily, then instantly collapses again    


        } else {
            alert(objData.SZERRMSG);
            return false;
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorMsgSanc + "\n" + xhr + "\n" + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

---

### UPDATE 4 (the solution)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: actionUrlSanc,
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        objData = JSON.parse(data); // CF gives us back a serialised struct, so deserialise it!
        if (objData.BSUCCESS == true) {
            // REMOVE THE POP-UP EDITOR WINDOW
            kendoWindow.close().destroy();
            // RELOAD THE DATASOURCE
            $('##offencesGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();        // New data is returned from database to datasource 

            // DO NOT TRY TO OPEN THE MASTER-ROW OF THE JUST-EDITED DETAIL ROW HERE
            // THE CODE NEEDS TO BE IN THE DATABOUND NODE OF THE GRID (see below)

        } else {
            alert(objData.SZERRMSG);
            return false;
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorMsgSanc + "\n" + xhr + "\n" + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
    }
});


$(document).ready(function () {

    $("##offencesGrid").kendoGrid({

        detailInit: sanctionDetail
        , dataBound: function (e) {

            // OPEN THE MASTER-ROW OF THE JUST-EDITED DETAIL ROW
            var grid = $("##offencesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            if (typeof masterRowIndex != 'undefined') {
                grid.expandRow(grid.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row:nth-child("+masterRowIndex+")"));
                // Destroy masterRowIndex after use so it doesn't persist if we move to a different agreement
                delete masterRowIndex;
            }

        }

        [the rest of the grid code... cut out for clarity/brevity]
    });

    function sanctionDetail(e) {

        // DETERMINE THE INDEX OF THE MASTER-ROW
        var objAllMasterRows = $("##offencesGrid").data("kendoGrid").tbody.find("tr.k-master-row");
        // Loop objAllMasterRows and discern the masterRowIndex
        $.each(objAllMasterRows, function(key, value) {
            if (value == e.masterRow[0]) {
                masterRowIndex = key+1;
                return false;
            }
        });

        [the rest of the dataRow code... cut out for clarity/brevity]
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using detailInit for details display?

Comment: yes I am
, detailInit: sanctionDetail

and I have a dataBound function just below it
, dataBound: function (e) {
 // Expand all Sanctions onload
 this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row"));
 // But really we only want to see the just-edited master-row expand. How...?
}

Comment: You can have a js variable that stores the last edited row. You set it in details init and then in the update function you pass it as argument for expandRow.

Comment: Do you have an example that helps to explain this?

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/OfESA expand a detail colapse it and using button you can expand the last detail.

Comment: the same principle can be applied to your case

Comment: The demo works great, and I (think I) have applied the same principle to my case, yet I cannot get the masterRow to expand. Please see my revised code in the UPDATE 1 section of the original post. Can you see where it might be going wrong?

Comment: It's because you recreate the grid and tr get recreated try to store and use the masterrow index instead this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row"):nth-child(masterRowIndex)

Comment: I tried a simple test with a hard-coded rowNumber, just to see if this would work, but no. See Update 2.

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/OfESA/4

Comment: Please see latest dojo - i did a coding mistake in previous comments

Comment: Thanks for the revision. I implemented it and we're 'almost' there (see Update 3). Now I can see the masterRow expand momentarily but then it collapses again, suggesting to me that something else in the action chain is subsequently reloading the grid in its original state after the expandRow() function has run. Where could that be?

Comment: Can you please check that databound event is not fired after and if so you can move your conditional expandind there

Comment: Yay! We finally have a working solution. For the benefit of others who come across this thread later, see Update 4. And thanks calinaadi for all the help!